# Android Arduino Bluetooth communication crash on starting

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino, ioexception

i have been trying to use bluetooth to comunicate between arduino and bluetooth
and there is no errors on build
tell me what is wrong 
i had issues with IO Exception but it solved now ... maybe
the app just crashes when i try to run it on phone 
help me i am not that good at java

```
    package com.example.administrator.myapplication;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import java.util.Set;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import android.os.ParcelUuid;





    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private Button onBtn, offBtn ,listBtn ,findBtn;
    private TextView text;

    private Button UpBtn ,DownBtn ,LeftBtn ,RightBtn;

    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    private ListView myListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> BTArrayAdapter;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private InputStream inStream;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (myBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            onBtn.setEnabled(false);
            offBtn.setEnabled(false);
            listBtn.setEnabled(false);
            findBtn.setEnabled(false);
            UpBtn.setEnabled(false);
            DownBtn.setEnabled(false);
            LeftBtn.setEnabled(false);
            RightBtn.setEnabled(false);

            text.setText("Status: not supported");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device does not support Bluetooth",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

           if(bondedDevices.size() > 0 ){

                BluetoothDevice[] devices = (BluetoothDevice[]) bondedDevices.toArray();
                BluetoothDevice device = devices[0];
                ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();
                 try{
                    BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
                    socket.connect();
                    outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                    inStream = socket.getInputStream();
                } catch (IOException e){

               }
            }




            //Movement
            UpBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Upbutton);
            DownBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Downbutton);
            LeftBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Leftbutton);
            RightBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Rightbutton);

            UpBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
                @Override public void onClick(View v)  {
                    try {
                        C(v, 8);
                    }
                       catch (IOException e ){

                           System.out.println("3 SEND FAILED");
                        }

                }
            });

            DownBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        C(v, 2);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("2 SEND FAILED");
                    }
                }
            });

            LeftBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)  {
                    try {
                        C(v, 4);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(" 4 SEND FAILED");
                    }

                }
            });

            RightBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    try {
                        C(v, 6);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(" 6 SEND FAILED");
                    }
                }
            }
            );

            //.........................
            //..................
            //Normal Code
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            //text.setText ( "" + myBluetoothAdapter.getName());



            onBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Onbutton);
            onBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    on(v);
                }
            });

            offBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Offbutton);
            offBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    off(v);
                }
            });

            listBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Listbutton);
            listBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    list(v);
                }
            });

            findBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Pairedbutton);
            findBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    find(v);
                }
            });

            myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            // create the arrayAdapter that contains the BTDevices, and set it to the ListView
            BTArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            myListView.setAdapter(BTArrayAdapter);
        }
    }

    public void on(View view) {
        if (!myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent turnOnIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnOnIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth turned on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is already on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                text.setText("Status: Enabled");
            } else {
                text.setText("Status: Disabled");
            }
        }
    }

    public void list(View view) {
        // get paired devices
        pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        // put it's one to the adapter
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
            BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Show Paired Devices",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // add the name and the MAC address of the object to the arrayAdapter
                BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                BTArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    public void find(View view) {
        if (myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            // the button is pressed when it discovers, so cancel the discovery
            myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        } else {
            BTArrayAdapter.clear();
            myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

            registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        }
    }

    public void off(View view) {
        myBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        text.setText("Status: Disconnected");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth turned off",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void C (View View , float H) throws IOException{
           if(H == 8){

                    outputStream.write("8".toString().getBytes());
           }
           if(H == 2){
                     outputStream.write("2".toString().getBytes());
           }
           if(H == 4){
                     outputStream.write("4".toString().getBytes());
           }
           if(H == 6){
                     outputStream.write("6".toString().getBytes());
           }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
    }

}
```

and here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.administrator.myapplication" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post logcat please .

Comment: wait a minute till i find it

Comment: i cant i dont have a phone on hand right now

Answer (score 1):

Solved it , it just was a permission error
just added the bluetooth_admin permission and it worked !!
thanks HaMiD Sani for pointing that out .

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty tough to point out the root of your problem without a log but this is the example https://goo.gl/d7YD92 (by google) that I followed a few months ago to make a robust bluetooth communication between android and arduino. Worked like a charge after a couple of hours of playing with it. One place I would also look is your manifest to make sure that you got all the necessary permissions.

Comment: here it is i posted it in the question

Comment: Glad to know that It helped. Don't forget to mark your response as the answer :)